# Cant see data in my node js server from another computer in my network

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I trying to open a local website on my local network that I can access from every devices in my network.
I use React as frontend, Nodejs as backend and mongodb is my database(Locally).

On the computer where everything is running I can enter the site through my address on the local network and see the data that is in the database, but as soon as I enter the site through another computer that is on the same network I see the site but not the data from the database.
How i can fix this ?

I use this code for the node js server and run `node server` in terminal:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ip = require('ip');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri);
const connection = mongoose.connection;
 connection.once('open', () => {
 console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully');
 });

const exercisesRouter = require('./routes/exercises');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/exercises', exercisesRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.use(express.static('../build'));

const path = require('path');
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.resolve('../build/index.html'));
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
console.log('server started on port:', PORT, ip.address());
app.listen(PORT,"0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how you're starting the react app, and also, how are you accessing the front end from other device?

Comment: @Mu-Majid Basically once I run the server then it runs the react app build files, as you can see in the code.
From another device I enter the site by typing in the address of the computer that running the server in the browser

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to specify the react HOST. If you're using `create-react-app`, Simply run HOST=your_ip npm run start.

To get this `your_ip`, run `ifconfig` on unix systems, and you'll find the IP for the your PC on the LAN you're connected to.

For the nodejs side, you might need to try something like

`server.listen(80, 'current_local_ip');`.

Comment: Basically it works with a slight change to port 5000.
It is possible to make it work without doing this command:`HOST=your_ip npm run start`, but only run the server?